# KDE keyboard shortcut to show taskbar

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde

In case of hiding KDE taskbar by default, how to show taskbar by keyboard shortcut, not by mouse hovering over the bottom of the screen. I seem can't find the keyboard shortcut to show taskbar in the KDE keyboard settings. Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure if that suits your needs, but you can define a shortcut for the Application launcher (the menu which opens if you press on the kmenu button in the taskbar).

The necessary steps are as follows:

- press right mouse button on kde button in the taskbar
- choose 'Application launcher settings'
- in the settings dialog set the keyboard shortcut

(This description is tested on KDE 4.9.2 but should work also for other releases).